# Custom pricing `catalog_product_get_final_price` and catalogrules

Tags: price, event-observer, catalog-price-rules

I'm implementing double customer group functionality for a B2B website in Magento 1. Essentially, a customer can have two customer groups, and the lowest price should be shown.

I've got it to work perfectly, both in the frontend & admin: I'm listening to the `catalog_product_get_final_price` (and `prepare_catalog_product_price_index_table`) event.

There is one issue:

**The event gets fired after the catalogrule module which means that catalogrules don't apply properly.**

Example product:

```
Base price:    $12
Group 1 price: $10
Group 2 price: $8
```

If a customer is part of both group 1 & 2, its price should be $8, and the catalogrule should be applied on that $8, not the $10 which is happening at the moment.

I can't make `Mage_CatalogRule` depend on my module to change the order of loading because modules that start with `Mage_` are always loaded first.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't make Mage_CatalogRule depend on my module to change the order
>   of loading because modules that start with Mage_ are always loaded
>   first.

But you can....
Let's say your module name is `Namespace_Module`.
Add this in the file `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`  inside the `<modules>` tag

```
<Mage_CatalogRule>
    <depends>
         <Namespace_Module />
    </depends>
</Mage_CatalogRule>
```

Comment: Ahh awesome - I guess Mage_ is always loaded first, but when the dependency resolution system kicks in, it will still put your module higher than the Mage one. Will check if it works